# Ubuntu 15 - Wi-fi connection silently dies after a few minutes

Tags: wireless

I have a brand new install of Ubuntu 15.04 and after a few minutes the wi-fi will stop working. It still shows as connected but with no real communication happening. No message of any kind is displayed.

The same happened with Ubuntu 14.04.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 16.04. Did you ever find out what was going on?